# Is there a way to identify which web framework is used in a site?

Tags: web-frameworks

Whenever I come across a [cute](http://sourcemaking.com/) website, I am always curious to know which web framework was used by its developers?

Being a novice in web development, a look at the page source doesn't give any clue.

Any way(s) to get this information? If possible, may be with a bit of Ruby magic, I can figure out things like: which is the most/least used framework for my favorite sites, audio/video heavy sites, etc.

Comment: Could be a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816231/how-do-you-tell-what-framework-language-a-web-site-is-using/816262#816262

Comment: Surprisingly, I failed to locate these prior to posting. May be I shall improve my searching skills:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046441/can-you-detect-what-framework-a-website-is-running-on-or-what-cms-they-use
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563316/is-there-a-generic-way-to-see-what-is-a-website-running-on 

Is there a 'merge' feature in stackoverflow to deal with this problem?

Comment: Just discovered, there is a close option to vote to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you can based on the URL patterns, or which scripts are included in the site ... but it's not a 100% predictor. You can write a site that completely masks the framework and simply delivers HTML/JS to the browser

Comment: Interesting to know and think about why would someone try to mask this information.